# Set a HTML page contents for printing

Tags: html, css

I have created a html document with 4 divs.

While printing I want the first and last div to be printed in one A3 sheet.
The 2nd and 3rd div in another A3 sheet and the size of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th div is A4 size.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have code? Looks like you might have to make a .pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this can be an answer: [css media types.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)